# setValue:forUndefinedKey: issue that makes no sense UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: ios6, uiactivityindicatorview, nsexception

In ViewController.m I am allocating a class like so:

```
myClass = [[MyClass alloc]init];
```

but when I set a breakpoint in that class it's throwing an exception before it even hits ViewDidLoad of:

```
[<MyClass 0x1a4a60> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key activityIndicator.'
```

But the thing is the class doesn't use an interface file and there is not a single UIActivityIndicatorView in the entire project. Can some please help, I have spent hours trying to address this and it makes no sense to me.

Comment: Have you checked the xib file of your ViewController to see if there is invalid outlet connection?

Comment: Yeah, just checked. There are no invalid outlet connections.

Comment: Maybe try to do clean build or even delete the app first from the simulator.

Comment: I did that, an deleted derived data. It doesn't make sense. If I comment out the line that allocates it, the app works, but if it's uncommented it crashes, despite there being no xib's and no Activity Indicators

Comment: Got it working. Had to delete the class completely from project and reimported and it worked.

Comment: wow its doing it again

Comment: Go to the project you imported it from, and see if it links to an activityIndicator in that project.